# Replacing cache control using web.config with new value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-config

I have an asp.net website which is sending by default the following cache in the header:

Cache-Control: private

I would like to change Cache-Control to:

```
no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
```

However, when I add the following to the web config:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<remove name="Cache-Control" />
<remove name="Pragma" />
<remove name="Expires" />
<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />
<add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
<add name="Expires" value="0" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

It still sends the "private" string in the Cache-Control header to the client:

```
Cache-Control
private,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0
```

You can notice how it does not even place a space after "private", it is still adding it to the beginning of the response.  How can I remove the "private" from Cache-Control using the web.config?  Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code to your web.config, **clear the browser’s cache and try again**.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, s-maxage=0" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a *sendCacheControlHeader="false"* attribute to the httpRuntime element in the system.web section fixed this for me.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" sendCacheControlHeader="false" />
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.suppressdefaultcachecontrolheader?view=netframework-4.8.1